# Why is jitterbit cloud data loader requireing me to login to Jitterbit Harmony

Tags: login, jitterbit

I got a new work pc and was installing Jitterbit and I can't get past this screen.  I don't want harmony and have never had to do this in the past.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that the Jitterbit Data Loader is the same code as their full product with some features disabled. It is essentially an agent on your computer that talks to Harmony which actually stores your transformations. [Here's an FAQ that discussed the differences](http://www.jitterbit.com/blog/jitterbit-cloud-data-loader-for-salesforce-faq/). I don't think previous versions of Data Loader are available.